# Add filename and length parameter to WCF stream when Transfermode = Stream

Tags: .net, wcf, streaming, filestream, wcf-client

In contrast to all the SO posts that talk about this topic, I'm not interested in wrapping a stream object in a `[MessageContract]`, since that is not permitted when in [streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) mode (afaik).

When I'm in streaming mode, how do I return to the client some metadata, such as length and filename?  Can I add a WCF/SOAP header?  How would I do this?

I am looking into extending the filestream class and add a `[MessageHeader]` attribute, but I'm unable to get this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is how we do it

```
     [MessageContract]
    public class StreamMessage
    {
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public long Length { get; set; }
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public int ServerVersion { get; set; }
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public byte[] Cerificate { get; set; }
        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        public Stream Stream;
    }
```

Comment: as you can see message contains Stream. And we use streaming all the way while sending very large files via https streaming.

Comment: That may be the case, but that is a forward only stream.  I need to pass the stream object to the client and need to support random seeks, reads, etc.  That is why I'm looking at WCF "Streaming Mode"

Comment: Isn't passing stream to client actually a StreamingMode?

Comment: No, it only happens when `Transfermode` is one of the defined settings. Restrictions section:  "Operations that occur across a streamed transport can have a contract with at most one input or output parameter"

Comment: Yes it is. But Message headers are _not_  parameters. Actually if you add additional property you will see nice exception message in WCF log.

Comment: @makerofthings7 you should return my UpVote back to me:)

Comment: Done!  Thanks for your patience in explaining this.

Comment: What's the point of `Order=1`? You only have one body parameter.